# op amp expression

Tags: operational-amplifier, amplifier

[image]
          ******Hi i don't undestand how the expression Uc1+R1*C1*dUc1/dt=Uout.... how was it made? Can someone give me hint or explain.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The current which flows through C1 and R1 is the same, and equals:

$$i_2=C_1\cdot \frac{dU_{c1}}{dt} = \dfrac{U_{out}-U_{c1}}{R_1}$$

Rearranging and solving for Vout:

$$U_{out} = U_{c1} + R_1 \cdot C_1\cdot \frac{dU_{c1}}{dt}$$

Answer (score 0):

Hint:

If voltage across capacitor is \$u\$, then the current through it is given by \$C\dfrac{du}{dt}\$

Comment: i think its a equation for low pass filter, but i don't get it why there is also Uc1 at the begining

Comment: No, it's just KVL. Notice that the inverting input is at \$0V\$. From there you addup the potentials across \$C1\$ and \$R1\$ to get the output voltage..

Answer (score 0):

[image]

That's Kirchoff's voltage law combined with the assumption that the opamp does its job i.e. the output settles to such Uout that the voltages at the inputs are forced to be equal. The changes in the voltages are assumed to be so slow that the speed of the opamp is high enough to retain the equality at the inputs.

So, the plus input is at 0V => The minus input is also at 0V . 
That's the virtual ground principle in the everyday electronics speak and it's a common shortcut to derive equations for opamp circuits.

Kirchoff:

Uout = the voltage of C1 plus the voltage of R1

The latter is determined by the current of C1 which depends on the changing rate of the voltage of C1.

That's it.